# Android app MySQL connection string Keyword not supported "Encrypt"

Tags: c#, android, mysql, azure

I am creating my first Android app including an Azure database connection.
I set up the SQL control based on the "MySQL Plugin v1.0" component.

When trying to connect the following System.ArgumentException shows up: 
Keyword not supported
Parameter name: "Encrypt"

Also changed the "Encypt" parameter to "SSLMode" and "SSL Mode" but the result is the same.

The connection string is working well in my regular C# applications.
Can you tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why you would like to connect to SQL directly, without backend?

Comment: I am creating a very simple app what only inserts certain informations into a database table, Similar way what I am doing in my other C# programs.
I am not sure, maybe it's wrong at all. Can you tell me how to do it properly?
I just followed a youtube video where it was working well.

Comment: how did you fix this? I have a similar problem: `Keyword not supported: 'e‌​ncrypt'.`

Comment: Finally couldn't fix to connect directly to my Azure DB.
Instead of it, started using a backend - Azure Mobile Services -> Easy Tables. Easy to use and working well.